# HTML tags inside Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, tags, thymeleaf

I need write text like: `<td th:text="${ticket.eventName} + '<br />' + ${ticket.ticketType}">Event Name</td>`
But `Thymeleaf` return error because of `<br />`. How I can solve this problem?

UPD: I try make like: `<td th:text="${ticket.eventName} + #{nextline} + ${ticket.ticketType}">Event Name</td>` and this works. `nextline` value = `\n`, but `#{nextline}` works only one time. If I paste it repeatedly it doesn't work, why?

UPD2: I solve this problem. Instead `'<br />'` need paste `'&lt;br /&gt;'` and `th:text` change to `th:utext`.

Comment: change `<br />` to `<br></br>`
[here is an explanation](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/HTML-tags-strict-checking-td4028045.html)

Comment: @Enigo Unfortunately it returns the same error

Comment: Have you tried `th:utext` instead of `th:text`?

Comment: @Enigo yes, I have and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 3):

You can use th:inline:

```
<td th:inline="text">
    [[${ticket.eventName}]]
    <br/>
    [[${ticket.ticketType}]]
</td>
```

More info: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining

Answer (score 3):

Tested for Thymeleaf 3.0:

```
<td th:utext="|${ticket.eventName} &lt;br/&gt; ${ticket.ticketType}|">Event Name</td>
```

Take note of [th:utext tag](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#more-on-texts-and-variables)

Other option:

```
<td>[[${ticket.eventName}]] <br/> [[${ticket.ticketType}]]</td>
```

See [Inlined output expressions](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/394)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip escaping the characters you can use th:block, which produces cleaner results.

> th:block is a mere attribute container that allows template developers
>   to specify whichever attributes they want. Thymeleaf will execute
>   these attributes and then simply make the block dissapear without a
>   trace. (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag)

So in your example:

```
<td>
    <th:block th:text="${ticket.eventName}"/>
    <br/>
    <th:block th:text="${ticket.ticketType}"/>
</td>
```